# Not being able to use an array sent in via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im sending in an array via props to a component, but i cant use map on the array. It says that

> .map is not a function

My code:

```
const AuthorList = (authors) => {
return(
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>Firstname</tr>
            <tr>Lastname</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {authors.map(author => 
                <AuthorListRow key={author.id} author={author} />
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
};
```

This is what the Chrome React dev tool looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, whenever you pass any data from parent to child, it get passed through props, and you need to receive the props in child component and access the specific values, write it like this:

```
const AuthorList = (props) => {
return(
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>Firstname</tr>
            <tr>Lastname</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.authors.map(author => 
                <AuthorListRow key={author.id} author={author} />
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
};
```

or

```
const AuthorList = ({authors}) => {
    return(
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>Firstname</tr>
                <tr>Lastname</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {authors.map(author => 
                    <AuthorListRow key={author.id} author={author} />
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

**Reason why 2nd one is working**: because props is an object, when you write `{authors}` it means you are receiving only `authors` value from object `props`. In that case you don't need to write `props.authors`.

Check this example:

```js
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
let {a} = obj;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know get why it wasnt working, it was the missing {} that fetches only authors from the props. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Props will be passed in as an object, so right now `authors` is acting as an alias for `props`. Accessing the `authors` property on `props` should work as long as that prop is being declared with an array.

```
const AuthorList = (props) => {
  return(
     // ..
            {props.authors.map(author => 
                <AuthorListRow key={author.id} author={author} />
            )}
     // ..
 );
};
```

Comment: The strange thing is I have the same pattern in another part of my app, and there its working, what is the difference that makes this code work?

const CourseList = ({courses}) => { ..........


                {courses.map(course => 
                <CourseListRow key={course.id} course={course} />
                )}

Comment: Those curlies around `courses` are an [object destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). That pulls `courses` out of `props` and is equivalent to using `props.courses` without the destructure. That's missing from the above `AuthorList` code.